# Dynamic Schema getDescribe

Tags: sobject, describesobject, sobjecttype, sobjectfield

I have two variables:

```
public String selectedObject {get; set;} //selectlist
public String selectedField {get; set;}  //selectlist
public String selectedDataType {get; set;}  //text
```

They are the selected values of my two dynamic picklist for selecting an object and then selecting a specific field and a text field for identifying its data type. I know that I can get the picklist values of a specific field a code like this:

```
public List<SelectOption> getPicklistValues() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    if (selectedDataType=='PICKLIST'){
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.Type.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        options.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
        }   
    }

   return options;

}
```

It can retrieve all the picklist values of the Type field of Account object.

The problem is it is not dynamic (I wanted to replace the **Account** with the **selectedObject** value and the **Type** with the **selectedField** value and as  long as the field type is **PICKLIST**.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of Account.Type (a specific field), you can use:

```
// Get the describe for the object
DescribeSObjectResult objResult = Schema.getGlobalDescribe()
                                    .get(selectedObject).getDescribe();
// Get the field dynamically
DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = objResult.fields.getMap()
                                  .get(selectedField).getDescribe();
```

At that point, you can get the picklist entries as normal. It's also possible from the field's describe to see if it's a valid picklist; simply call .getType() and see if it's a DisplayType.Picklist, DisplayType.MultiPicklist, or DisplayType.Combobox. If so, you can safely get the picklist values.

Answer (score 2):

For performances, it's prefered to use **Schema.describeSObjects** method instead of **Schema.getGlobalDescribe**.

I did some performance tests and found it faster (time execution) and consume less Heap size.

```
List<Schema.DescribeSObjectResult> descResults = Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>{sObjectName});
```

Example : retrieving recordTypeId by developerName

```
// Execution time : 31.21 ms
// Heap size 6272
for(Integer i=0;  i<100; i++){
Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>{'Account'}).get(0).getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Customer_Account').getRecordTypeId();
}

// Execution time : 1156.46 ms
// Heap size 312672
for(Integer i=0;  i<100; i++){
Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Customer_Account').getRecordTypeId();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for the contribution. Not that I disbelieve you, but please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/358998/edit) your answer to add some of the numbers that you got when comparing execution time and heap size. Many (dare I say "geeks"?) in this SFSE audience would love to see *how much* faster and *how much* smaller.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I added some Numbers related to my performance tests.